# Connecting to localhost works fine, but I can't connect to most subdirectories on localhost. What's wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

I just recently installed and configured Apache, PHP, and MySQL according to the instructions here: http://danilo.ariadoss.com/how-to-setup-apache-php-mysql-on-mac-os-x-105-leopard/

Except I installed MySQL (including the StartupItem and PreferencePane) following the instructions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-pkg.html

When I open a browser and navigate to localhost, my `~/Sites/index.html` page is displayed.

When I tried to navigate to any of my `~/Sites` subdirectories via `localhost/subdir`, however, I got the following error:

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the >server was attempting to fulfill the request.

These subdirectories were all in `~/Sites` before I configured Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

I made another directory in `~/Sites` (`~/Sites/test`) after configuring Apache, PHP, and MySQL to which it seems I'm able to connect via `localhost/test` (the contents of the index.php file in `~/Sites/test` are displayed upon directing a browser to `localhost/test`).

In other words, I'm not able to connect to my old `~/Sites` subdirectories, but for some reason I can connect to new `~/Sites` subdirectories. I moved all the contents of an old subdirectory to a new (empty) subdirectory, then tried connecting to the new subdirectory but got the same error.

Before I configured Apache, PHP, and MySQL according to the instructions above, I was running my Sites subdirectories with MAMP. Could that have something to do with this error message?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Look at apache's error log - it'll have more details about whatever caused the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a file permission problem. Maybe the files under MAMP have different permissions that your new installation of Apache is not allowed to access.

500 errors are also commonly caused by misconfigured `.htaccess` files. These are hidden configuration files that might still exist even if you emptied a directory. Try enabling the view of hidden files in your Finder and then browse around in your problematic subdirectories.  Let me know if you  see any.

If not we'd have to check your old subdirectories permissions and compare them with the new ones, to see if there is a difference. If the permissions are different, it explains why your system is not letting Apache access those files. This can be accomplished via the Terminal, using the `ls -l` command. I'm on Linux and haven't touched a Mac in a while but I think you can also see a file's permissions (which user it belongs to, etc) by right-clicking and selecting Properties.

Let me know if any of this makes sense.

Comment: I don't see any hidden files in any of my subdirectories, nor are the old subdirectories' permissions any different from the new one's (all are drwx-r-xr-x).